# What is the ipv6 equivalent of 0.0.0.0/0

Tags: networking, ipv6

When describing IPv4 networks, I can use `0.0.0.0/0` or just `0/0` to specify all networks. What is the equivalent notation for IPv6?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The IPv6 equivalent of IPv4's `0.0.0.0` is `::/0`.

Answer (score 18):

`::/0` is the short-form, but you could also write out all the zeros if you want.
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/0